# Groovy: Split one segment if condition of other segment matches

Tags: groovy

Could anyone please help me in the groovy code for this requirement. I have an XML input such as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Tesco</FieldName>
         <Mode>As Is</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>

      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>ASDA|Tesco|Walmart</FieldName>
         <Mode>Split</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Orange|MTS</FieldName>
         <Mode>Break</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
</result>
```

When the value of field `Mode` is either `Split` or `Break`, then I need to spilt the segment using pipe delimiter, and I need to change the value of field `Mode` to `1,2` etc. based on the splitting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Tesco</FieldName>
         <Mode>As Is</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>

      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>ASDA</FieldName>
         <Mode>1</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>

      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Tesco</FieldName>
         <Mode>2</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>

      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Walmart</FieldName>
         <Mode>3</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
   <records>
      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>Orange</FieldName>
         <Mode>1</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>

      <dataProcessed>
         <FieldName>MTS</FieldName>
         <Mode>2</Mode>
      </dataProcessed>
   </records>
</result>
```

Comment: "Please do it for me" questions are offtopic on SO. Please try yourself and come back with concrete problems or questions you have.

Comment: Have you tried any? Is the xml data element `dataProcessed` fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `dataProcessed` nodes and then for each, check the value of `Mode` and act accordingly on the nodes.